# IFile returns null

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using eclipse plugin development and trying to modify file but when i get `IFile` Object it always returns null.

below is snippets.

```
 IEditorInput pui = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor().getEditorInput();
 IFile part = (IFile) Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(pui, IFile.class);
```

Comment: What is the actually class of the editor input `pui`? Not all editor inputs are based on files.

Comment: Where is your file? Is it inside or outside your Eclipse workspace?

Comment: It is inside my workspace created project in runtime workspace and added .feature file and trying to modify the same using Ifile.

Comment: @greg-449 :- IEditorInput

Comment: No that is an interface, the actual class - something like `FileEditorInput`. Debug the code and see what the actual class is.

Comment: @greg-449 : -org.eclipse.ui.part.FileEditorInput(/test/src/New Text Document.feature)

Comment: Then this should work provided you are calling in a reasonable place in a properly initialised RCP. You could try casting from `IEditorInput` to `IFileEditorInput` and calling the `getFile` method.

Comment: @greg-449 :- no luck getting org.eclipse.ui.part.FileEditorInput cannot be cast to org.eclipse.ui.IFileEditorInput

Comment: Well then you are doing something very odd because FileEditorInput implements IFileEditorInput so the cast should always work unless you are loading things from different class loaders. You need to edit the question and explain to us in much more detail what you are doing.

Comment: One thing that would cause issues like this is including Eclipse plugin jars in your plugin. For example putting a copy of things like the `org.eclipse.core.resources.xxx.jar` inside your plugin.